# Best way to contain information with different shapes in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to implement conditional variational autoencoder for MNIST images with convolutional layers, not flattening. So the image itself is `[batch_size, 28, 28, 1]` (greyscale). I want to concat the label with the image input. But I can't concat the above shape with `[batch_size, 10]`. I was thinking of expanding the images for example like `[batch_size, 38, 28, 1]`, or just adding a new "row" - to make the shape `[batch_size, 29, 28, 1]`, and until 10 the "column" values would mean the class of the image, but it doesn't feel the correct way to do it. Anyone met with the same issue before? What's the "right"(est) way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensorflow you can define a model that has more than one input and because of this there really is no reason to imbed one kind of data (labels of MNST) into another kind of data (pixels of images). They can be model'd separately and combined at whatever step in the model you would like. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np

#Random Data
X1 = np.random.random((1000,28,28,1))
X2 = np.random.random((1000,10))
Y  = np.random.random((1000,10))

#Create Model

x11 = tf.keras.layers.Input((28,28,1)) #Input of first data
x12 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x11)
x13 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(x12) 

x21 = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,))     #Input of second data
x22 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(x21)

c1  = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([x13,x22]) #Combine data together
c2  = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(c1)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([x11,x21],c2)
model.compile('adam','mse')
model.fit([X1,X2],Y,epochs=10)
```